# Julia - Gurobi : Changing bounds

Tags: julia, linear-programming, gurobi

Is there any way to change either all or (prefferably) a single bound of a Gurobi.Model in Julia?

I have a Gurobi.Model, `lp = Gurobi.Model(env)`
I can view lower/upper-bounds using `lowerbounds(lp)` or `upperbounds(lp)`
and view specific bounds, fx 5, with `lowerbounds(lp)[5]` etc
However, I cant find a way to set specific bounds to a new value other than by re-initializing the whole thing

Comment: Why aren't you using [JuMP](http://www.juliaopt.org/JuMP.jl/0.13/index.html)? (which is internally wrapping the same lib you are using) It also has some docs regarding problem modification [here](http://www.juliaopt.org/JuMP.jl/0.13/probmod.html).

Comment: JuMP somehow manages to be immensely slow, so slow infact that using GLPK directly is alot faster than CLPEX through JuMP, and orders of magnitude slower if I use GLPK through JuMP

Comment: That sounds like something you should report as an issue in the JuMP repository or in the julia-opt mailing list with a minimal reproducible example of the slowdown.